# how to put string that contains japanese character conditionally into separate arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

I just asked [how to put string conditionally into separate arrays in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66790275/how-to-put-string-conditionally-into-separate-arrays-in-javascript?noredirect=1#comment118065698_66790275)
and it gave me a great hint, but could not fix my actual problem.

I asked as alphabet and number to simplify my question but actual string contains 2 types of Japanese character: kanji and hiragana.

Do you think do same thing as the answer in the previous question somewhat?
I will leave examples here

(example 1)

string: 生き残る (生, 残 => kanji き, る => hiragana)

result: [生],[き],[残],[る]

(example 2)

string: 楽しい (楽 => kanji しい => hiragana)

result: [楽],[しい]

---

and this is what I tried (and failed)

```
let regexForKanji = /([\u{3005}\u{3007}\u{303b}\u{3400}-\u{9FFF}\u{F900}-\u{FAFF}\u{20000}-\u{2FFFF}][\u{E0100}-\u{E01EF}\u{FE00}-\u{FE02}]?)/mu

let regexForHiragana = /[\u{3000}-\u{301C}\u{3041}-\u{3093}\u{309B}- \u{309E}]/mu



let string = "生き残る"

function ja2Bit ( str ) {
  return ( str.match(`${hiragana}+|${kanji}`)) 
}

ja2Bit(string)

//VM534193:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: //[\u{3000}-\u{301C}\u{3041}-\u{3093}\u{309B}-\u{309E}]/mu+|/([\u{3005}\u{3007}\u{303b}\u{3400}-\u{9FFF}\u{F900}-\u{FAFF}\u{20000}-\u{2FFFF}][\u{E0100}-\u{E01EF}\u{FE00}-\u{FE02}]?)/mu/: Range out of order in character class
```

sorry for asking multiple times. Thanks guys.

---

update

ok I found solution, and it will work for hiragana, kanji, and karakana as well! Thanks guys for help!

solution

```
'生き残りタイのか'.match(/^[\u30a0-\u30ff]+|[\u3040-\u309f]+|[\u30e0-\u9fcf]+|[\u30a0-\u30ff]+|[\u3040-\u309f]+/g)
//["生", "き", "残", "り", "タイ", "のか"]
```

Comment: I would assume this is possible. If we know the code range for Kana then everything else could be treated as Kanji? https://www.key-shortcut.com/en/writing-systems/%E3%81%B2%E3%82%89%E3%81%8C%E3%81%AA-japanese

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thanks for answer, actually I already have regex but could not make it work. I added in question so have a look when you get time :D

Comment: We don't do library recommendations, but for this, I'd definitely look for one in your position. It seems that [Wanakawa.js](https://github.com/WaniKani/WanaKana) (which I never tried myself) has the `tokenize()` method you are looking for.

Comment: I updated my answer to have a better function and to support unicode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'生き残りタイのか'.match(/^[\u30a0-\u30ff]+|[\u3040-\u309f]+|[\u30e0-\u9fcf]+|[\u30a0-\u30ff]+|[\u3040-\u309f]+/g)
//["生", "き", "残", "り", "タイ", "のか"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex.

This should give you a place to start, but I would use regexr and tweak the below to fit your needs.

```
/[一-龠]+|[ぁ-ゔ]+|[ァ-ヴー]+|[a-zA-Z0-9]+|[ａ-ｚＡ-Ｚ０-９]+|[々〆〤]+/u
```

```
let string = "生き残る";

function ja2Bit(str) {
    const kanji = /[\u4E00-\u9FFF]/mu;
    const hiragana = /[\u3040-\u309Fー]/mu;
    if (str.match(kanji)) {
        return `${str} is kanji`;
    } else if (str.match(hiragana)) {
        return `${str} is hiragana`;
    } else {
        return "I don't know";
    }
}

ja2Bit(string);
```

https://regexr.com/