# Is there a javaScript method that can split sentences in different languages into arrays of words？

Tags: javascript

Is there any javascript method that can split sentences in different languages into word arrays after removing spaces and punctuation marks?

- example（English）：“So we'd do a thorough clean of all surfaces in each room, and polish them where necessary.”
  Word combinations like (we'd) are retained as a whole without splitting；
- example（Japanese）：“時間が過ぎて、あっという間に冬休みは過ぎてしまった。冬休みの生活を思い出して、嬉しくなった！”；
- example（Korean）：세상에서가장큰시간낭비가아니던가요?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords:nlp

Comment: Would be possible with latin languages, but with korean or japanese, not sure. You can use `replace()` to remove all spaces  and `split()` to split. Then push to an array

Comment: Found this for Japanese: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66790785/how-to-put-string-that-contains-japanese-character-conditionally-into-separate-a

Comment: @Aastha That's not splitting *by word*. That needs extensive [tag:nlp] libraries to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may look into [`Intl.segmenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Segmenter):

```js
const text = '時間が過ぎて、あっという間に冬休みは過ぎてしまった。冬休みの生活を思い出して、嬉しくなった！';

const words = [...new Intl.Segmenter('ja-JP', { granularity: 'word' }).segment(text)].map(({ segment }) => segment);

console.log(words);
```

Comment: While impressive, it yields fairly unimpressive results for me, like `[..., "嬉", "しく", "な", "っ", "た"]`. That should all be one word.

Comment: Yes, it's not perfect. A nlp library is required for more accurate result.